# Creating a for loop that draws pixels close together to make a square shape look filled in with color

Tags: c++

Hopefully, my title makes a little bit of sense. I am new to programming and trying to create a for loop that draws pixels on the x-axis and then on the y-axis to make it look like a square shape with the pixels making it looked filled in. How would I go about doing this? As of right now whenever I run the code I get a diagonal line from the bottom left of the screen to the top right. I know there are probably more optimal ways of doing this but for the point of this assignment that I am working on it is required. Here's what I've got so far but again I can't stress this enough, I am very new to c++ programming. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, MAX is just an int set to 728 and SetPixel is (int x, int y, unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue).

```
void drawRectangle(int parameterX, int parameterY) {

// draw rectangle
for (int x = 0; x > parameterX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y > parameterY; y++) {
        SetPixel(x+y, MAX / 2, 255, 255, 255);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the both loop test are backwards.  Also you don't seem to be asking a question; please read [ask] as _"...Any help would be greatly appreciated..."_ is not really a question in the SO format.

Comment: its not 100% clear what is the problem. You should have explained what is wrong. Probably this is just a typo and `x > parameterX` should be `x < parameterX` (same for `y`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There'se issues with your code. First, the loop definition `for (int x = 0; x > parameterX; x++)` states that `x > parameterX` in order for the loop body to execute, likewise with  `for (int y = 0; y > parameterY; y++)` with `y > parameterY`. From the code you posted it would seem that the rectangle (or square if `parameterY == parameterX`) goes from 0 to `parameterX` in the x-axis and from 0 to `parameterY` in the y-axis. Hence you should change your code to

```
void drawRectangle(int parameterX, int parameterY) {

// draw rectangle
for (int x = 0; x < parameterX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < parameterY; y++) {
        SetPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 255);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `SetPixel(int x, int y, unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue)` seems to take `x` and `y` as the current pixel's x and y coordinate, that's why it is called like `SetPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 255);`. Also note that `MAX / 2` is dropped because it would fix your y-coordinate to that value **always** during the loop, and finally note that parameters `red`, `green` and `blue` are the color components of an RGB color space, the final color is the combination of those three channel values, and those values go from 0 to 255, that's why these parameters are defined as `unsigned char`. The new code is read as, *for every pixel in the rectangle going from 0 to `parameterX` in the x-axis and from 0 to `parameterY` in the y-axis then set the pixel's red component to 255, green component to 255 and blue component also to 255*. In RGB colorspace that color is *white*.

Comment: Man, I feel real dumb for not noticing that! Thank you for explaining everything, that helps me tremendously :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither the question nor accepted answer reveals what C++ library OP uses. I assume that this is Win32 API. If so, `SetPixel` takes an `HDC` handle as the first argument (see the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel). With this in mind, here's code that works and solves OP's problem:

```cpp
int r=123;
int g=123;
int b=123;

HWND myconsole1 = GetConsoleWindow()
HDC hdc1 =GetDC(myconsole1);
COLORREF Colors1= RGB(r,g,b); 
//draw rectangle
for (int x = 0; x < parameterX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < parameterY; y++) {
        SetPixel(hdc1,x, y,Colors1);
   }
}
```

Comment: this answer will work it worked for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you propose an answer, especially to a relatively old question that already has some answer(s), please always indicate what your answer adds to the existing ones. As far as I can see, yours adds nothing. Please compare your extremely brief answer to the accepted one to learn what a good answer is. People who visit SO usually do not come here for black-box code snippets that work, but, rather, they want to learn.  So, write your answers to teach OP, not to provide them with magical black boxes.

Comment: zkoza javier silva code dident work for me so i wrote this code look at it closely it does not draw black boxes i dont know how so there is no point of unvoting the the answer you could give it 0 because it works still if you use varibles r,g,b to fix that lol!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.>
#include<Windows.h>

HWND Console = GetConsoleWindow();

int main()
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(Console);

    for(int x = 200; x < 250; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 200; y < 250, y++)
        {
            setPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(0, 200, 0));
        }
    }

    system("pause>0");

    return 0;
}
```